# Passing on value of variable of anonymous function in R

Tags: r

I've created a convenience function with a couple of wrappers that, for the purposes of this question, converts any inputs into strings except if the symbols refer to a character object (checks for that omitted below), in which case it adds the contents of that object to the output.

All works fine except trying to use anonymous functions, where I end up capturing the name of the variable in the anonymous function, rather than its value. How do I capture the value instead?

```r
my_wrapper <- function(...) { 
  
  
  input <- rlang::enquos(...)
  
  convert_all_args_to_strings(input)
  
}

convert_all_args_to_strings <- function(input) {
  
  expressions <- lapply(input, rlang::quo_get_expr)
  
  types <- vapply(expressions, typeof, FUN.VALUE = character(1))
  
  str_from_character <- unlist(expressions[types == "character"])
  
  symbols <- vapply(expressions[types == "symbol"],
                    FUN.VALUE = character(1),
                    rlang::as_name)
  
  objects <- mget(symbols, ifnotfound = list(NULL), 
                  inherits = T)
  
  str_from_objects <- unlist(objects)
  
  confirmed_symbols <- vapply(objects, is.null, 
                              FUN.VALUE = logical(1))
  
  
  str_from_symbols <- symbols[confirmed_symbols]
  
  c(str_from_character, str_from_symbols, 
    str_from_objects, use.names = FALSE)
  
  
}



places <- c("here", "there", "somewhere")

# DESIRED OUPTUT
my_wrapper("hier", "da", aqui, alla, places)
#> [1] "hier"      "da"        "aqui"      "alla"      "here"      "there"    
#> [7] "somewhere"

# DESIRED OUPTUT
lapply(places, my_wrapper, bla, bla, bla)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "here" "bla"  "bla"  "bla" 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "there" "bla"   "bla"   "bla"  
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "somewhere" "bla"       "bla"       "bla"

# WRONG OUPTUT
lapply(places, function(x) my_wrapper(x))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "x"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "x"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "x"
```

Comment: Try `lapply(places, function(...) my_wrapper(...))` or `lapply(places, function(x) my_wrapper(!!x))`. If you call the function with `my_wrapper(x)`, your function will only be able to see the `x`. This is why it's a bad idea to have functions that insist on having values passed as symbols rather than characters. They are much more difficult to program with.

Comment: thank you, @MrFlick! That does work, but I'm after something that works like `lapply(c("name", "skin_color"), function(x) dplyr::select(starwars, x))` does. If it can't be done in base R, I'll try with tidyselect. I was hoping for some pointers either way.